# RCU stall error after grub loads

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, windows-7

Ths is the first time I got this problem and I have not been able to find a solution. I read about a guy with a similar problem with his server and he edited grub adding the `nosmp` command in the config file (but I can't access linux so I don't know how to do it.)

The thing is, I installed Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu 18.04 (4 days ago), all was working fine until 2 days I selected the Ubuntu option in GRUB and it didn't load anything. The screen just go black, and after some time appears an error message that says something like

```
rcu_sched detected stalls on cpus/tasks
```

and

```
rcu_sched kthread starved
```

It says something about CPU #0 at the end of the line and something about a time lapse that change, but the error message it's the same.

My PC is a laptop (POSITIVO BGH J430) / Pentium Dual Core T4500 / Intel chipset.

As I said, never happened before, I'm using this Windows alongside Linux since Ubuntu 14.xx (only SO). But this time I installed Win7 alongside Ubuntu. If anyone has dealt with this and solved it, please tell me what you did to fix it.

If not my final solution is re-install Ubuntu with no Win7.
Thanks!

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1.21

$ sudo dmidecode -t 1,2**
# dmidecode 3.1

Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.

SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: POSITIVO BGH
    Product Name: POSITIVO BGH
    Version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    UUID: 0A73EE80-D2AA-0000-0000-000000000000
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Family: To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: POSITIVO                       
    Product Name: J14                            
    Version: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

`ls -al /boot`

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Mar 26 12:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root     4096 Mar 26 12:12 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   224446 Jul 29  2019 config-5.0.0-23-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   235831 Feb 28 07:40 config-5.3.0-42-generic
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Mar 26 12:16 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 40771504 Mar 25 23:08 initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 41457066 Mar 26 12:15 initrd.img-5.3.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  4289273 Jul 29  2019 System.map-5.0.0-23-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4485514 Feb 28 07:40 System.map-5.3.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  8707832 Aug  5  2019 vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  9142520 Feb 28 07:41 vmlinuz-5.3.0-42-generic `
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106114/discussion-on-question-by-sebastian-medina-almagro-rcu-stall-error-after-grub-lo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fsck**

First we check/repair your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier

  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda5`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**initrd.img-5.3.0-42-generic**

System was/is running fine on the `5.0.0-23-generic` kernel.

`Software Updater` updated the kernel to `5.3.0-42-generic` and things broke. Now it's having trouble loading the ramdisk, which indicates that there might be a problem with the `/boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-42-generic` file, so we'll create a fresh copy.

Whilst booted to the -23 kernel...

In `terminal`...

`sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.3.0-42-generic` # create new initrd.img

`reboot` # to the -42 kernel

**BIOS**

```
POSITIVO BGH J430 (or J14), current BIOS is version 1.21
```

You need to check for a newer BIOS. Start at [this website](http://www.positivobgh.com/productos/soporte).

**Update #1:**

Seems like the -23 kernel works fine, and the -42 kernel doesn't. We'll modify GRUB so that it always boots to the -23 kernel. (ie: it'll boot to the last selected choice). Then wait for the next system software update, where hopefully they've got a better kernel for your machine.

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

Near the top of the file, edit/change/add these lines...

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved    # change existing line
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true # add this line
```

`sudo update-grub`

`reboot`

At the GRUB menu, choose Additional Options, then choose the -23 kernel. After booting completely, reboot, and see if it returns to the -23 kernel again on its own.